# Mysql: нужен ли столбец "счетчик/id" в таблице отношений

Tags: mysql

Есть 3 таблицы:

`items (item_id,...)` | `tags (tag_id,...)` | `tags_rel (item_id, tag_id)` + внешние ключи.

1. Нужен ли в таблице tags_rel AUTO_INCREMENT/PRIMARY столбец id/i?
   т.к. количество тегов и итемов не превысит MEDIUMINT UNSIGNED, а вот количество взаимоотношений может превысить.
2. Нужно ли ставить параметр PRIMARY столбцам в tags_rel и каким?

p.s. Если можете поделиться полезными статьями на эту тему, буду очень благодарен

Comment: При наличии уникального индекса по `(item_id, tag_id)`, если в основном используется именно установление соответствия между записями основных таблиц, а не ссылки на соотношение, разумно сделать такой индекс первичным, и не создавать синтетического ключа. Иначе - первичный ключ скорее нужен, чем нет.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Нет, автоинкремент там не нужен.

Да, первичный ключ нужен, составной, прямо по вашим полям как есть `.. key(item_id, tag_id)`

upd.: почитать можно маны, например [13.1.14 CREATE INDEX Syntax](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/create-index.html) и [8.3.5 Multiple-Column Indexes](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/multiple-column-indexes.html)

upd2.: плюс есть вероятность (смотря какие у вас запросы) что оптимизатор в некоторых случаях будет в первую очередь искать по полю, которое в составном индексе не на первом месте. тогда первичный ключ не будет использоваться и вам придётся добавить ещё один ключ или по второму полю или составной по двум полям, но в обратную сторону - `(tag_id, item_id)`. explain и профилирование запросов в помощь.

Comment: Спасибо! До этого запросы были вида SELECT item_id FROM table WHERE tag_id IN (...). И наоборот